# how to select a complex xml tag containing key value pairs that have a specific string using xslt

Tags: xml, loops, xslt, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have an xml file as shown below

```
    <Envelope>
   <body>
      <lineItemList>
         <!--1 or more repetitions-->
         <lineItem>
            <id>1</id>
            <customData>
               <!--1 or more repetitions-->
               <paramKVPair>
                  <name>EQUIPMENT_TYPE1</name>
                  <value>Non-Client - TV</value>
               </paramKVPair>
               <paramKVPair>
                  <name>authorName</name>
                  <value>Wireless Bridge</value>
               </paramKVPair>
               <paramKVPair>
                  <name>manufacturer</name>
                  <value>Wireless Bridge</value>
               </paramKVPair>
            </customData>
         </lineItem>
         <lineItem>
            <id>2</id>
            <customData>
               <!--1 or more repetitions-->
               <paramKVPair>
                  <name>EQUIPMENT_TYPE</name>
                  <value>Non-Client - TV</value>
               </paramKVPair>
               <paramKVPair>
                  <name>authorName</name>
                  <value>Wireless Bridge</value>
               </paramKVPair>
               <paramKVPair>
                  <name>manufacturer</name>
                  <value>Wireless Bridge</value>
               </paramKVPair>
            </customData>
         </lineItem>
      </lineItemList>
   </body>
</Envelope>
```

i need an xslt for-each loop with condition to select all the lineItems which have a customData/paramKVPair with a name 'EQUIPMENT_TYPE' and the value for that paramKVPair should be either 'Wireless Bridge' or 'Non-Client - TV'.

Here is the xslt i have tried:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="Envelope/body/lineItemList/lineItem[ contains(customData,'EQUIPMENT_TYPE') and (contains(.,'Wireless Bridge') or contains(.,'Non-Client - TV'))]">
<id><xsl:value-of select="./id"/></id>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this xslt is selecting all the lineItems even if any one string is present in the customData.

In the above case, i need the output should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<id>2</id>
```

I need such a for-each statement because i have some other conditions to incorporate in the same.

Can any one please help me in this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the XPath expression `Envelope/body/lineItemList/lineItem[customData/paramKVPair[name = 'EQUIPMENT_TYPE' and (value = 'Wireless Bridge' or value = 'Non-Client - TV')]]`.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, but that is not giving any output at all. not even the xml decleration line.
Is the condition allowed that way? nested square brakets?

Comment: Yes, its working. I had missed a space in my condition.
Thanks alot.